# How can I use jPOS-EE library to read pos terminal configuration and change them remotely,

Tags: java, remote-access, point-of-sale, iso8583, jpos

How can I monitor, manage and change configurations of POS terminals remotely with the help of java jPOS-EE library

I am try to manage and monitor POS(Point of Sale) terminals remotely. Knowing who has which POS terminals, what is happening on which POS terminal? Modify POS terminal configurations

Answer (score 0):

While some POS software implementations use the ISO-8583 protocol (mostly network management 800-class messages) where you can use jPOS, most others use proprietary protocols and provide their own TMS systems. So unfortunately, the answer to your question is: it depends.